# how to split an array according to their difference in value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an ordered array like the following:

```
const arrayToSplit = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 21, 23];
```

which I want to be split into multiple arrays where the difference between one and another is max a value, let us say 2:

```
const result = [ 
  [1, 3, 5],
  [8, 10, 12],
  [21, 23]
];
```

or 8:

```
const result = [ 
  [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12],
  [21, 23]
];
```

and so forth. I have a solution but is far away from an elegant one, where I run the array by using an accumulator variable. Is there a neater, more elegant solution?

A possible solution to this:

```
function splitArray(arrayToSplit = []){
  const explodedArray = [];

  let elementsNewArray = [];
  for(const element of arrayToSplit) {
    if(elementsNewArray.length == 0) {
      elementsNewArray.push(element);
      continue;
    }

    if(element - _.last(elementsNewArray)) <= 2) {
        elementsNewArray.push(element);
    } else {
        explodedArray.push(elementsNewArray);
        elementsNewArray = [element];
    }
  }

  explodedArray.push(elementsNewArray);
  return explodedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems reasonably straightforward to simply keep track of the last item iterated over in a variable. When iterating, check if the difference between that and the current item being iterated is larger than the limit. If it is, push a new array. Regardless. push the item being iterated over to the last array in the collection.

```js
const arrayToSplit = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 21, 23];
const maxDiff = 2;

const result = [[arrayToSplit[0]]];
let last = arrayToSplit[0];
for (const item of arrayToSplit.slice(1)) {
  if (item - last > maxDiff) result.push([]);
  result[result.length - 1].push(item);
  last = item;
}
console.log(result);
```